# How can i dynamically change the tray icon image in JavaFX like dropbox tray icon

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, awt, javafx-8, trayicon

In dropbox, the tray icon dynamically change. 
When file is uploading, sync icon is shown. 
When all file is synchronized, dropbox show other icon(latest status icon).

https://mockupstogo.mybalsamiq.com/projects/icons/Dropbox

I want to develop a same function using JavaFX

At first call, trayIcon.setImage is normally working (blue color tray icon is shown).
but second call, it is not working (gray color tray icon is not shown). 
It just show empty box.

Is it JavaFX bugs?

```
package application;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;


public class Main extends Application {
// one icon location is shared between the application tray icon and task bar icon.
// you could also use multiple icons to allow for clean display of tray icons on hi-dpi devices.
//private static final String iconImageLoc =
//  "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/scafer31000/bubble-circle-3/16/GameCenter-icon.png";

//private static final String iconImageLoc1 =
//  "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/metro-halloween/96/Cauldron-icon.png";

// application stage is stored so that it can be shown and hidden based on system tray icon operations.
private Stage stage;

// a timer allowing the tray icon to provide a periodic notification event.
private Timer notificationTimer = new Timer();

// format used to display the current time in a tray icon notification.
private DateFormat timeFormat = SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance();


private TreeView<String> treeView;

// sets up the javafx application.
// a tray icon is setup for the icon, but the main stage remains invisible until the user
// interacts with the tray icon.
@Override public void start(final Stage stage) {
    // stores a reference to the stage.
    this.stage = stage;

    // instructs the javafx system not to exit implicitly when the last application window is shut.
    Platform.setImplicitExit(false);

    // sets up the tray icon (using awt code run on the swing thread).
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this::addAppToTray);

    // out stage will be translucent, so give it a transparent style.
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

    // create the layout for the javafx stage.
    StackPane layout = new StackPane(createContent());
    layout.setStyle(
            "-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);"
    );
    layout.setPrefSize(300, 200);

    // this dummy app just hides itself when the app screen is clicked.
    // a real app might have some interactive UI and a separate icon which hides the app window.
    layout.setOnMouseClicked(event -> stage.hide());

    // a scene with a transparent fill is necessary to implement the translucent app window.
    Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    stage.setScene(scene);

}

/**
 * For this dummy app, the (JavaFX scenegraph) content, just says "hello, world".
 * A real app, might load an FXML or something like that.
 *
 * @return the main window application content.
 */
private Node createContent() {
    Label hello = new Label("hello, world");
    hello.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 40px; -fx-text-fill: forestgreen;");
    Label instructions = new Label("(click to hide)");
    instructions.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 12px; -fx-text-fill: orange;");

    VBox content = new VBox(10, hello, instructions);
    content.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    return content;
}

/**
 * Sets up a system tray icon for the application.
 */
private void addAppToTray() {
    try {
        // ensure awt toolkit is initialized.
        java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

        // app requires system tray support, just exit if there is no support.
        if (!java.awt.SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            System.out.println("No system tray support, application exiting.");
            Platform.exit();
        }

        // set up a system tray icon.
        java.awt.SystemTray tray = java.awt.SystemTray.getSystemTray();
/*            URL imageLoc = new URL(
                iconImageLoc
        );

        URL imageLoc1 = new URL(
                iconImageLoc1
        );
        java.awt.Image image = ImageIO.read(imageLoc);

        java.awt.Image image1 = ImageIO.read(imageLoc1);*/


        Dimension size = tray.getTrayIconSize();
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(size.width, size.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();

        g.setColor(java.awt.Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

        System.out.println(size.width);
        System.out.println(size.height);
        java.awt.TrayIcon trayIcon = new java.awt.TrayIcon(bi);


        // if the user double-clicks on the tray icon, show the main app stage.
        trayIcon.addActionListener(event -> Platform.runLater(this::showStage));

        // if the user selects the default menu item (which includes the app name), 
        // show the main app stage.
        java.awt.MenuItem openItem = new java.awt.MenuItem("hello, world");
        openItem.addActionListener(event -> Platform.runLater(this::showStage));

        // the convention for tray icons seems to be to set the default icon for opening
        // the application stage in a bold font.
        java.awt.Font defaultFont = java.awt.Font.decode(null);
        java.awt.Font boldFont = defaultFont.deriveFont(java.awt.Font.BOLD);
        openItem.setFont(boldFont);

        // to really exit the application, the user must go to the system tray icon
        // and select the exit option, this will shutdown JavaFX and remove the
        // tray icon (removing the tray icon will also shut down AWT).
        java.awt.MenuItem exitItem = new java.awt.MenuItem("Exit");
        exitItem.addActionListener(event -> {
            notificationTimer.cancel();
            Platform.exit();
            tray.remove(trayIcon);
        });

        // setup the popup menu for the application.
        final java.awt.PopupMenu popup = new java.awt.PopupMenu();
        popup.add(openItem);
        popup.addSeparator();
        popup.add(exitItem);
        trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popup);



        // create a timer which periodically displays a notification message.
        notificationTimer.schedule(
                new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
                            trayIcon.displayMessage(
                                    "hello",
                                    "The time is now " + timeFormat.format(new Date()),
                                    java.awt.TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO
                            )
                        );

                        System.out.println(size.width);
                        System.out.println(size.height);
                        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(size.width, size.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                        Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();

                        g.fillRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
                        g.setColor(java.awt.Color.GRAY);

                        trayIcon.setImage(bi);

                    }
                },
                5_000,
                60_000
        );

        // add the application tray icon to the system tray.
        tray.add(trayIcon);

        //trayIcon.setImage(image1);
    //} catch (java.awt.AWTException | IOException e) {
    } catch (java.awt.AWTException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to init system tray");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Shows the application stage and ensures that it is brought ot the front of all stages.
 */
private void showStage() {
    if (stage != null) {
        stage.show();
        stage.toFront();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, java.awt.AWTException {
    // Just launches the JavaFX application.
    // Due to way the application is coded, the application will remain running
    // until the user selects the Exit menu option from the tray icon.
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in different image sizes , you change second icon with sizes of first!

Comment: I modified a source code to use a buffered image. First and second call has same size (16*16), but problems are same. I can not change blue color tray icon to gray color tray icon

Comment: I have changed with gimp the size of second image to 16x16 and so the icon was visualizated ... I use your previous code sample

Comment: Thank you Mailkov. It is visualized when i use same size icon. But i still don't know, why it is not working on the color change using bufferedImage. Anyway, Thank you Mailkov